# array merge issue in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge array in php. I have array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 3 [2] => 15 )
Array ( [0] => IMAGE [1] => TICKER [2] => FULL_SCREEN_VIDEO )
Array ( [0] => 434 [1] => 423 [2] => 123 )
```

And I want result like:

```
Array( [0] => 6 [1] => IMAGE [2] => 434)
Array( [0] => 3 [1] => TICKER [2] => 423)
Array( [0] => 15 [1] => FULL_SCREEN_IMAGE [2] => 123)
```

What will be the easiest solution for this kind of problem?
Thanks..

Comment: What you want to do is called "transposing".

Answer (score 2):

You want to "transpose" an array.  Assuming you have these 3 arrays in an array, you can do this:

```
$array = array(
    array(6, 3, 15),
    array('IMAGE', 'TICKER', 'FILL_SCREEN_VIDEO'),
    array(434, 423, 123)
);

array_unshift($array, null);
$array = call_user_func_array("array_map", $array);
```

If your arrays are actually 3 separate arrays, then you could just simply do this:

```
$array = array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3);
```

<sub>That's basically what `call_user_func_array` is doing.</sub>